# Weird behavior of program on force closing one end of pipe

Tags: c++, piping

I am trying to create a rudimentary 2 person chat program using pipes. The code below goes into infinite loop if an application connected to the other end of the pipe is forced closed. The second program is same the as this except the names of the pipes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_BUF 1024
void *th()
{
    int fd;
    char myfifo[] = "/tmp/myfifo2", buf[MAX_BUF];
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    while(buf=="");             
    while(1)
    {
        read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("Stranger : %s\n", buf);
        if(!strcmp(buf,"exit"))         
            break;  
        else buf[0]='\0';
    }
    close(fd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char myfifo[] = "/tmp/myfifo", msg[25];
    pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, th, NULL); //error
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    while(msg!="exit")
    {
        printf("You : ");
        gets(msg);
        if(!strcmp(msg,"exit"))
            {write(fd, msg, sizeof(msg));  break;}
        else write(fd, msg, sizeof(msg));
    }
    close(fd);
    unlink(myfifo);
    return 0;
}
```

### My output :

[image: output]

How do I ensure the application exits on force closing of the application?

Comment: I've posted an answer, ignoring the line `while(buf=="");` which I assume is a copying mistake (also, never true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't check the return for `read()` and `write()`.

Since a failed read won't fill `buf` with the string "exit", your break condition never occurs.

Comment: So closing one end of the pipe does not disable the pipe? Coz `(!strcmp(buf,"exit")||(!strcmp(buf,"")))` seems to work.

Comment: At the end of each loop, you set `buf[0] = '\0'`. Since the `read()` doesn't update the buffer, it remains an empty string.

Comment: Also why does `pthread_create` give me an error: `invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’`. I have to use `-fpermissive` while compiling. I didn't understand this error.

Comment: Because your function signature is incorrect. `pthread_create()` expects a function taking a void pointer, and returning a void pointer, ie. `void *func(void *arg)`

Comment: So what to do? Write `(void *)` as I do not want to pass ? I do not know what to do in such cases. See edit for error code.

Comment: @VedVals: You can ignore the argument. It should exist.  If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.